# if/else statement for scrolltop jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, scrolltop

I'm having some problems in writing my own jQuery script

Here's the problem, I wanted to create a button that slide the window down
and I used if/else statement to determent the situation.

here's the code:

```
var main = function() {

    $('.down').click(function() {

    var x= $(window).scrollTop();
    alert(x);
    var s;

    if (x < 500){
      s = 500;
    }else if(500 <=x<700 ){
      s = 700;
    }else{
      s=1000;
    };

    $('html, body').animate(
      {scrollTop: s}, 1000);

    });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

However, when the window slide to 700, it no longer execute the next else statement which scroll to 1000.
any ideas? :(

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `})`; after the `.animate` call.  But, then it shouldn't run at all.

Comment: Try to check these values one by one `else if (500 <= x && x < 700)` and like Jeremy said, the animate method not correct.

Comment: Sorry, the animate function is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your else if is incorrect.

```
}else if(500 <=x<700 ){
```

should be

```
}else if(500 <= x && x < 700 ){
```

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nygb9dgq/)